# Microsoft Office Excel 2007 - Hyperlink Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I am currently working on a spreadsheet where I am referencing drawings throughout the document. I have the drawings saved in the same folder as the spreadsheet.

When sending the document externally is there any way that I can keep the same hyperlinks that I have used? Currently it's reading through my C: drive or /desktop file path which the recipients can't find.

Answer (score 0):

If it where me I would include them all in a .zip or .rar file and just leave the links with no UNC path, giving instructions in the E-mail to extract the files to a folder before opening the Excel document.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the hyperlink just make sure the address specified does not include a path.  When following a hyperlink without a full path, the actual path is relative to the excel file folder.  You could include a relative path is required.

Examples

```
Path = DrawingFile.dwg              looks in same folder as excel file for DrawingFile.dwg
Path = .\DrawingFile.dwg            looks in same folder as excel file for DrawingFile.dwg
Path = ..\DrawingFile.dwg           looks in parent folder of excel file for DrawingFile.dwg
Path = Drawings\DrawingFile.dwg     looks in Drawings folder in as excel file folder for DrawingFile.dwg
Path = C:\Drawings\DrawingFile.dwg  looks in folder C:\Drawings\ for DrawingFile.dwg
```